# What is the difference between stdin with fscanf and scanf

Tags: c, scanf

I want to get a integer from to user. But I wonder what is the difference between `fscanf(stdin, "%d", &x);` and  `scanf("%d", &x);`?

Comment: What have you researched yourself about this? Where is the problem?

Comment: They’re the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you #defined `fscanf`, `scanf` or `stdin`, both calls will do the same thing.  Note that such redefinitions would invoke undefined behavior.

Some standard input output functions have shorter versions for dealing with `stdin` or `stdout`:

- `fscanf(stdin, ...)` is equivalent to `scanf(...`
- `getc(stdin)` is the same as `getchar()`
- `putc(c, stdout)` can be written `putchar(c)`
- `fprintf(stdout, "Hello world\n");` is usually shortened to `printf("Hello world\n");`

Answer (score 3):

> What is the difference between stdin with fscanf and scanf?

The `scanf` function is equivalent to `fscanf` with the argument `stdin` interposed before the arguments to `scanf`.  C11 §7.21.6.4 2

So aside from a different amount of typing the code, they are the same.